# Use input value and insert it on form action

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm currently trying to make a page system to my project.

My objective is to when someone type a number to a input and presses enter, the page will refresh with that page selected.

This is a part of my code:

```
<?php   
if ($page>1) 
    echo "</b><a class='btn btn-primary' style='background: #384452' href='read_topic.php?id=".$id."&page=".($page-1)."'> < Anterior</a> ";  
     ?>
```

I get a undefinable variable to nrpng here

```
<form action="read_topic.php?id=<?php echo $id;?>&page=<?php echo $_POST['nrpng'];?>" method="post">
 <input type="number" name="nrpng" style="width:67px; line-height: 2em; text-align:center;" min="1" max="<?php echo $total_pages; ?>" value="<?php echo $page; ?>">
    </form>
```

The rest of the code:

```
<?php if ($page<$total_pages) 
    echo " <a class='btn btn-primary' style='background: #384452' href='read_topic.php?id=".$id."&page=".($page+1)."'>Próxima ></a>"; 
?>
```

Comment: In JavaScript changing the location is as easy as `location = 'someURL.php?prop1=val1'`.

Comment: `$_POST['nrpng']` wont exist on first load, it will only exist after the form has been posted

Comment: @PHPglue can you explain a little more please, I'm kinda newbie at this.

Comment: Do you want virtual pages or are you actually trying to just go to a page based on user input.

Comment: Just trying to go to a page based on user input, you input a number of a page and you get redirected to that page, simple as that.

Comment: [First Page] [**Number of Page**] [Last Page], When the user introduces a number, he will redirect him (set the $_GET value of &page = Number) to that page

Answer (score 1):

Amaro,

Look, the problem you've here is that the $_POST variable is not been set the first time you load the page or when you select the 'next' or 'previous' links.

So what you need to do is to initialise the value to be able to handle those cases, for that you should do something like:

```
<?php
$nrpng = (isset($_POST['nrpng']) ? $_POST['nrpng'] : '');

//further down in your code
<form action="read_topic.php?id=<?php echo $id;?>&page=<?php echo $nrpng;?>" method="post">
```

However, I would recommend that you send those variables using 'hidden' fields instead of through the 'action' of the form, more so if you're using method 'POST', and in general is more elegant.

Hope that this solve your issue

[EDITED]

Looking at what you wrote on the questions above, I think you've a misunderstanding on how the forms works. Let me help:

The 'input' you've in the form will be passed to the server when the user hits enter after writing a number. Therefore you don't need to edit the action of the form for it to be passed. As example:

```
<form action="read_topic.php" method="post">
<input type="number" name="nrpng" style="width:67px; line-height: 2em; text-align:center;" min="1" max="<?php echo $total_pages; ?>" value="<?php echo $page; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>
</form>
```

This should suffice to have the information you want when the "read_topic.php" script runs.

Then in that script you can have the $_POST variable with the following variables set: 'id', 'nrpng' and you can do the logic required to render that page for that id.

However you need to remember to initialise the values of those variable to prevent errors when loading the first time.

Comment: I get what you mean, but when I use this code, it redirects me to this link:
- read_topic.php?id=1&page=**Blank**

I'm going to do some testings and I will see if it works

Comment: Thank You for having the time to write this great answer, but I think I reached a conclusion with what you wrote before, but thank you anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want something like:

```js
//<![CDATA[
// external.js
var doc, bod, htm, post, C, E, T; // for use on other loads
addEventListener('load', function(){ // load start

// I threw in a few goodies to study - it will help you later
doc = document; bod = doc.body; htm = doc.documentElement;
function phpEncode(obj){
  var r = [];
  if(obj instanceof Array){
    for(var i=0,l=obj.length; i<l; i++){
      r.push(phpEncode(obj[i]));
    }
    return '%5B'+r.join(',')+'%5D';
  }
  else if(typeof obj === 'object' && obj){
    for(var i in obj){
      if(obj.hasOwnProperty(i)){
        var v = obj[i], s;
        if(typeof v === 'object' && v){
          s = encodeURIComponent('"'+i.replace('"', '\\"')+'":')+phpEncode(v);
        }
        else{
          v = typeof v === 'string' ? '"'+v.replace('"', '\"')+'"' : v;
          s = encodeURIComponent('"'+i.replace('"', '\\"')+'":'+v);
        }
        r.push(s);
      }
    }
    return '%7B'+r.join(',')+'%7D';
  }
  else{
    r = typeof obj === 'string' ? '"'+obj.replace('"', '\\"')+'"' : obj;
    return ''+r;
  }
}
function phpAccept(url){
  return eval('('+decodeURIComponent(url)+')');
}
post = function(send, where, success, context){
  var x = new XMLHttpRequest;
  var c = context || this;
  x.open('POST', where); x.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
  x.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(x.readyState === 4 && x.status === 200){
      if(success)success.call(c, phpAccept(x.responseText));
    }
  }
  if(typeof send === 'object' && send && !(send instanceof Array)){
    if(send instanceof FormData){
      x.send(send);
    }
    else{
      var r = [];
      for(var p in send){
        r.push(encodeURIComponent(p)+'='+phpEncode(send[p]));
      }
      x.send(r.join('&'));
    }
  }
  else{
    throw new Error('send must be an Object');
  }
  return x;
}
C = function(tag){
  return doc.createElement(tag);
}
E = function(id){
  return doc.getElementById(id);
}
T = function(tag){ // returns an Array of Elements by tag name
  return doc.getElementsByTagName(tag);
}
E('form').addEventListener('submit', function(ev){
  ev.preventDefault();
});
var page = E('page'), err = E('error');
var pr = 'Positive Integer Required';
function gF(){
  var val = page.value;
  if(val.match(/\d+/)){
    location = 'yourPageHere.php?page='+val;
  }
  else{
    err.innerHTML = pr;
  }
}
E('go').addEventListener('click', gF);
page.addEventListener('keydown', function(ev){
  if(ev.keyCode === 13)gF();
});
page.addEventListener('keyup', function(){
  err.innerHTML = page.value.match(/^[1-9]+[0-9]*$/) ? '' : pr;
});

}); // end load
```

```css
/* external.css */
html,body{
  padding:0; margin:0;
}
.main{
  width:980px; margin:0 auto;
}
#contain{
  width:116px; background:#070; color:#fff; padding:10px;
}
#contain>label{
  display:block; float:left; width:40px;
}
#page{
  width:30px; float:left;
}
#go{
  display:block; width:40px; margin:0 auto;
}
#error{
  width:136px; color:#900; text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html;charset=utf-8' />
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='external.css' />
    <script type='text/javascript' src='external.js'></script>
  </head>
<body>
  <div class='main'>
    <form id='form'>
      <div id='contain'>
        <label for='page'>Page:</label><input id='page' name='page' type='text' value='1' />
        <input type='button' id='go' value='GO' />
      </div>
    </form>
    <div id='error'></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Of course, you should change `'yourPageHere.php?page='` to suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I finally reached a conclusion, Thanks for me helping me Arturo (and rest of the people of course)

What I did was this:

```
  <form action="read_topic.php?id=<?php echo $id;?>" method="post">  

$nrpng = (isset($_POST['nrpng']) ? $_POST['nrpng'] : '');
if (!empty($nrpng)){ ?>
    <script> window.location = "read_topic.php?id=<?php echo $id;?>&page=<?php echo $nrpng; ?>";</script>

      <?php exit();
    }
?>
```

Everytime a POST like this is submitted it redirects to that page and exits there.

Don't worry I've worked out with the negative values, maximum and minimum too!